# Undefined variable: userName in sending mail laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i need to send email when the ticket saves but am getting the error am guessing am supposed to put the values in array is my syntax okay?

**ErrorException
Undefined variable: userName**

This is the store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
      // Create Ticket
      $ticket=new Ticket;
      $ticket->userName= $request->input('userName');
      $ticket->userEmail= $request->input('userEmail');
      $ticket->phoneNumber= $request->input('phoneNumber');
      $ticket->regular_quantity= $request->input('regular_quantity');
      $ticket->vip_quantity= $request->input('vip_quantity');
      $ticket->event_id=$request->route('id');
      $ticket->total= $request->input('regular_quantity') + $request->input('vip_quantity');



      $event = Event::find($ticket->event_id);
      if ($ticket->regular_quantity < $event->regular_attendies && $ticket->vip_quantity < $event->vip_attendies) {
          if($event->regular_attendies>0 && $event->vip_attendies>0){
        DB::table('events')->decrement('regular_attendies', $ticket->regular_quantity);
        DB::table('events')->decrement('vip_attendies', $ticket->vip_quantity);
        $ticket->save();

      $to_name = '$userName';
      $to_email = '$userEmail';
      $data = array('name'=>"$userName", "body" => "Test mail");

        Mail::send('layouts.mail', $data, function($message) use ($to_name,$to_email){
        $message->to('$userEmail');
        $message->subject('Ticket success');
        $message->from('kisilamapeni@gmail.com','kisila');
    });
       echo "Email sent";

    }
       else{
          echo"no available space";
       } 
       return redirect('/');

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do here.

```
$to_name = '$userName';
$to_email = '$userEmail';
```

Setting `$to_name` to `'$userName'` will result in the string `'$userName'`, which seems pointless.

Also, you're getting an error in this line:

```
$data = array('name'=>"$userName", "body" => "Test mail");
```

When you wrap a variable in `" "`, it tries to parse it, but you don't have a variable `$username`.

An easier way to accomplish this is to ignore setting these values and simply pass the newly created `$ticket` to your email, and reference the correct parameters:

```
$data = array("name" => $ticket->userName, "body" => "Test mail");
Mail::send("layouts.mail", $data, function($message) use ($ticket){
  $message->to($ticket->userEmail);
  $message->subject("Ticket success");
  $message->from('kisilamapeni@gmail.com','kisila');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You never define the variable $userName (and the same mistake for $userEmail). Use

```
$to_name = $request->input('userName');
$to_email = $request->input('userEmail');
```

and then also

```
$data = array('name'=> $to_name, "body" => "Test mail");
```

You also have an error in your Mail:: send function

```
$message->to($userEmail);
```

should be

```
$message->to($to_email);
```

You will also need to define

Comment: indeed, I was copy-pasting from the author